# Log likelihood question I need help with

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

Could someone explain part c) of this question to me please as it has me confused. Parts a) and b) were fine but c) is confusing me.

Thanks,

IS
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function having a negative derivative over an interval implies that the function is decreasing over that particular interval.

Given that $x=0$
$$\ell'(p) = -\frac{n}{1-p} < 0 \quad \text{ for all } 0  \leq p < 1.$$
Therefore, $\ell(p)$ is decreasing function. Furthermore, the maximum of $\ell(p)$ must occur at $p = 0$.

Comment: This makes sense thank you, it occurs at p = 0 because this is where the point is least negative. Was thrown by the wording in the text.

Comment: Ah... I see how that could be confusing. Glad to have been of some use.